# Selecting last consecutive sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I select the last element in a sequence of adjacent elements?

Consider the following markup:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">...</li>
    <li class="foo">...</li>
    <li class="foo">...</li> <!-- bingo -->

    <li class="bar">...</li>
    <li class="bar">...</li>
    <li class="bar">...</li>
    <li class="bar">...</li> <!-- bingo -->

    <li class="foo">...</li> <!-- bingo -->

    <li class="bar">...</li>
    <li class="bar">...</li> <!-- bingo -->
</ul>
```

The number of consecutive `foo` or `bar` elements is dynamic. Also, assume the markup cannot be modified in any way.

Selecting adjacent elements is pretty straight forward:

**CSS**

```
.foo + .foo, 
.bar + .bar { /* do something */ }
```

But selecting the last element in a series of consecutive elements, is that possible?

Comment: nop, you need javascript. css could do .foo + .bar or :last-of-type

Comment: Can you wrap them inside of something else? You need a way to separate them so you can use the `:last-child` selector.

Comment: @Luxelin hm.. But wrapping list items by what? The only valid child of `<ul>` is `<li>`.

Comment: @HashemQolami I guess a different class would be the only way to do it.

Comment: If the list items are generated dynamically (via JavaScript or a server side programming language), you could add a class like `last`  to relevant list items in order for them to be selectable.

Comment: @HashemQolami - sounds like there's no avoiding the modification of the markup. Perhaps adding a class would be the least invasive option.

Comment: Some years have passed since this question was asked.  Have any new selectors been added to the css spec that can handle this case?

Comment: Not yet, as far as I can tell; the only resolution was a less than optimal JavaScript solution suggested above that adds a class for easier targetting.

Answer (score 4):

The CSS support for `:has` is still poor but it can solve the problem:

```css
/* selects any .foo that has no .foo immediately after it  */
.foo:has(+ :not(.foo)) {}
```

Comment: That is definitely very promising, if only it had ANY kid of support! At the time, it's 0% with Safari Technology Preview being the only browser supporting it: https://caniuse.com/css-has

Comment: I'm going to upvote your answer, however cannot select it as the answer until I can validate it works :)  Very crafty find!

Comment: Status check - as of today, CanIUse is showing support for 84% of global users for this pseudo selector. Good enough for my purposes, so this is a win!

Answer (score 0):

You must be dynamically setting up the list.... in that case give a name or an id to the last element and add the css effect you want....

What you asked is not possible according to me unless you have some way of recognizing the last element (may be the id or the name, again set this up if you are in control)

Comment: I was hoping there would be some way to combine the selectors such that the `.foo + .foo` could be combined with `last-child` - but I guess there really is no way to do that yet (or perhaps ever).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do this without changing the HTML or the way you generate it. However, if you generate it via the `.append()` method, all you'd have to do to use this (theoretically) is change it to `.prepend()`. If you do that, you can change the ul's css to have it select backwards, and then you can use the + selector like so:

(edit: I don't know how to reorder the snippet, but the JS is the least important and only there for if you want to see the `.prepend()` in action)

```js
//some generation examples just for fun

foo.addEventListener('click',addKnown);
bar.addEventListener('click',addKnown);
r.addEventListener('click',addRandom);

function addKnown(e) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.className = e.target.id;
  li.textContent = e.target.id;
  document.querySelector('ul').prepend(li);
}
function addRandom(e) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  let type = ['foo','bar'][Math.round(Math.random())];
  li.className = type;
  li.textContent = type;
  document.querySelector('ul').prepend(li);
 }
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

li:first-of-type,
.foo+.bar,
.bar+.foo {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bar">bar</li> <!-- bingo -->
  <li class="bar">bar</li>

  <li class="foo">foo</li> <!-- bingo -->

  <li class="bar">bar</li> <!-- bingo -->
  <li class="bar">bar</li>
  <li class="bar">bar</li>
  <li class="bar">bar</li>

  <li class="foo">foo</li> <!-- bingo -->
  <li class="foo">foo</li>
  <li class="foo">foo</li>
</ul>

<!-- some generation examples just for fun-->
<button id="foo">Add foo</button>
<button id="bar">Add bar</button>
<button id="r">Add random</button>
```

I would also recommend giving the ul some sort of class or id unless you only have one or want this to be the case for all of your uls on the page.

I'm sorry, I know this isn't exactly what you wanted (because it does technically change the markup by making it backwards), but I hope it's something that's at least possible or helpful in finding something that is.

Answer (score -2):

There appears to be an nth-last-child selector:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-last-child/

You should be able to use it with a zero argument to get the last one

Edit: nth-last-child will indeed select the last child, which does not match the bingo's

Hopefully you can change the structure:

```
<ul>
   <ul>
       <li class="foo">foo 1</li>
       <li class="foo">foo 2</li>
       <li class="foo">foo 3 bingo</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
       <li class="bar">bar 1</li>
       <li class="bar">bar 2</li>
       <li class="bar">bar 3</li>
       <li class="bar">bar 4 bingo</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
       <li class="foo">foo 1</li>
       <li class="foo">foo 2 bingo</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

and this css will work:

```
.foo:nth-last-child(1),
.bar:nth-last-child(1)
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: To get that last element, `last-child` would be sufficient - but that still doesn't solve the problem of selecting that last matching element in a consecutive series of siblings (see the bingo marks in the markup).

Comment: true technophobia, had missed that. Maybe it does not answer your question, but if you can change the structure of the unordered list, then it will work. (it might help someone else in the future)

Comment: I assume, by what OP said abt it being dynamic, that they're adding the `li`s one at a time with one class or the other, not knowing where in the list they'll be at the time. If that's the case, this would be a huge hassle.